# ZedGraph Pie Label: How to display Value and Percent, but not Name?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am using [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) to display some pie charts in my C# WinForms application. I want to display a legend and also the labels next to each pie slice in the following format:

**Legend**: Each item should display the Name of the pie slice, e.g. `"Customers"`

**Slice Label**: Each label should display value and percent, e.g. `"4 (25%)"`

By default I am able to have the legend displaying the name as desired. So on to the label requirement...

I have looked into the `LabelType` property, which allows me to select a few options for the label format ([here is the list](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_PieLabelType.htm)). Unfortunately, there is no `Value_Percent` option. I cannot use the ones that include the Name because they are too long and it ruins the display of the labels.

I though perhaps I could set the text label myself as I am able to calculate both the Value and Percent anyway, so I tried this:

```
pieItem.Label.Text = myCustomString;
```

This does get my desired labels, but it also sets the legend key format to be the same - so I lose that requirement of Name.

Is it possible to change the slice label text independent of the legend text? Or, is it possible to achieve my requirements another way?

Comment: Why not use the ZedGraph support area for that? http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/support

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: Have you looked at it? It's dead, nobody has gotten any responses to any of their questions

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a dead OS project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to achieve my requirements by modifying the source code. I would still be interested in knowing if there is a way to do it without making source changes, but in the mean time here is what I did...

The source code can be [downloaded from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20source/5.1.5/), and I used version 5.1.5 so my line number references may be wrong in other versions.

There are two segments of code that need to be added, in two separate files:

*ZedGraph/Types.cs*

There is an `enum` called `PieLabelType` located at `line 729`. Here we need to add a new value called `Value_Percent`.

*ZedGraph/PieItem.cs*

There is a function called `BuildLabelString` located at `line 942`. Within this function is a `switch` statement that we need to add a new condition for our new `PieLabelType`:

```
case PieLabelType.Value_Percent:
    curve._labelStr = curve._pieValue.ToString("F", labelFormat) + " (" + (curve._sweepAngle / 360).ToString("P", labelFormat) + ")";
    break;
```

I have chosen the format `"# (#.##%)"`, obviously this can be anything that is required.

That's it. Just build the project and then include the new modified DLL in your application and the new `PieLabelType` will be ready to use.

Comment: Submit a pull request, see if there's still any life left in it.

Comment: Why not use `string.Format("{0:F} ({1:P})", curve._pieValue, curve._sweepAngle / 360);`

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: Because I went with what was already there for Name_Value_Percentage and just removed the name bit.